# Creating a visualization with observations randomly generated over the entire area of a plot

Tags: r, d3.js, random, plot, ggplot2

**In short, I am looking for help with creating a plot in which a specific area of the plot is designated to a certain randomly assigned observation (who possesses a certain factor designated by color).  I'd prefer ggplot2 or d3.**

I was in a discussion today and was trying to demonstrate the point that even if we randomly chose an observation, we would probably pick an observation of interest.  In other words, if every observation was randomly assigned to a certain part of a dartboard and I threw a dart, chances are that my dart would hit an observation that would be of interest

Now, I'm now literally trying to create this dartboard.

I've been messing around with ggplot2 and I've come close to visualizations that I want but not quite.

First, I tried using geom_polar.  I randomly generated coordinates for each observation

```
df$Coord1 <- sample(50, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
df$Coord2 <- sample(50, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
```

and then plotted them The problem here, though, is that all of the area of the plot was not taken.  (There's also the issue that some points actually overlapped... so if someone also knows how to generate coordinates that wouldn't ever overlap that would be nice.)  If I were to throw a dart, I might not hit an observation. Here's the code I used:

```
dartboard <- ggplot(df, aes(Coord1, Coord2, fill = Classification)) +
geom_tile()+coord_polar()
```

[image: Attempted Dartboard 1]

So, then I tried my hand with a pie chart.

```
pie <- ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(1), fill = factor(Classification))) +
geom_bar(width = 1) +  coord_polar()
```

[image: Attempt #2]

which was nice because it was a whole circle, but it grouped the classifications together when I want them randomly scattered across the plot.

I also tried replicating this heat map creation (http://www.r-bloggers.com/controlling-heatmap-colors-with-ggplot2/) but I wasn't quite able to figure out how to make it fit correctly with my data.

In short, I am looking for help with creating a plot in which a specific area of the plot is designated to a certain observation who possesses a certain factor.

Any ideas?

Update 1:

This code is what I'm looking for visually from the conceptual level (all part of the chart is covered by an observation:

```
df <- expand.grid(x = 1:20, y = 1:20)
samples <- c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
df$series <- samples[runif(n = nrow(df), min=1,max=length(samples))]
g <- ggplot(df, aes(fill=series, xmin = x, ymin = y, xmax = x+1, ymax = y+1))
g <- g + geom_rect()
g <- g + coord_polar(theta="y")
g <- g + theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
g <- g + theme(axis.text=element_blank())
g <- g + theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())
g
```

[image: Attempt 1]

but now I'm trying to figure out how to apply this to my own data set which has about 1,500 observations.  The coordinates in that picture are used with expand.grid, so now I'm trying to figure out how to assign coordinates to my own 1,500 observations.

Update 2:

I have relative success with the code below.

[image: Success]

```
random <- expand.grid(x = 1:40, y = 1:39)

random <- random %>%
  mutate(ID = 1,
         ID = cumsum(ID))

plot.data <- full_join(data, random, by = "ID")

samples <- c("UI", "IN", "OW", "BE" , "Five")
plot.data$Classification <- samples[runif(n = nrow(plot.data), min=1,max=length(samples))]
g <- ggplot(plot.data, aes(fill=Classification, xmin = x, ymin = y, xmax = x+1, ymax = y+1))
g <- g + geom_rect()
g <- g + coord_polar(theta="y")
g <- g + theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
g <- g + theme(axis.text=element_blank())
g <- g + theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())
g <- g + scale_fill_manual(values=c("dark green", "orange" , "yellow" , "red" , "green"))
g
```

I used the expand.grid function to assign coordinates to kids.  Some observations got left out because they couldn't be given coordinates, but that's okay.

My only concern/complaint now is that some observations are larger (and thus easier to hit) than others.... so I might examine that heat maproute.  Time will tell.  Thank you very much for the help so far.

Update 3:

Another version (and probably final form):

[image: Final form]

This way, each observation is roughly the same size.

The base of this heatmap version can be found here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/controlling-heatmap-colors-with-ggplot2/ but here's my own code

```
ggplot(plot.data, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = factor(Classification))) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("dark green", "orange" , "yellow" , "red" , "green")) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  theme_change
```

Comment: You say "randomly assigned" without specifying a distribution. This is too imprecise, there are all kinds of ways to "randomly assign" samples to a dartboard.

Comment: Also I am inferring from your picture that your sample space is a space of four outcomes ("BE", "IN","OW","UI") that can be occur repeatedly, but you don't actually say what it is (or show us what your data frame `df` looks like)

Comment: I didn't specify a distribution because I didn't want to be picky. Use any distribution you want -- I just want every pixel to contain an observation.  As far as the df, by itself it's just two variables, ID and Classification.  I just generated the Coord1 and Coord2 variables because I was just trying to randomly assign coordinates.  

My sample has about 1,200 observations each with 1 of 4 classifications (BE, OW, IN, UI).

Sorry for not being clearer.

Comment: Good to know now, and looks like Rico64 guessed it correctly, but I clearly did not get it from your description :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this?

```
df <- expand.grid(x = 1:20, y = 1:20)
samples <- c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
df$series <- samples[runif(n = nrow(df), min=1,max=length(samples))]
g <- ggplot(df, aes(fill=series, xmin = x, ymin = y, xmax = x+1, ymax = y+1))
g <- g + geom_rect()
g <- g + coord_polar(theta="y")
g <- g + theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
g <- g + theme(axis.text=element_blank())
g <- g + theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())
g
```

Comment: This is creating an observation at every point on the pie chart. I thought he wanted to create observations at random points and show that it was likely he would get an observation. But I admit it is not really clear what he wants, and this might be it.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for from the conceptual level.  I'm not at work anymore but when I have the data I'll try and replicate this with my ~1,200 observations.

Comment: So that works on the conceptual front but now I'm trying to get each observation a unique x and y. That part is tricky because I have a specific # of observations while the expand.grid makes a 400 obs one.  I have 1,500 observations.  I might just have to do expand.grid(1:38) ....